# Submit spark using rest api outofmemory

Tags: json, rest, hadoop

I am trying to [submit a spark job directly via the YARN REST API](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/28070/starting-spark-jobs-directly-via-yarn-rest-api.html), but it is going wrong with an Out Of Memory error:

```
2016-08-18 18:33:01,691 INFO  [ContainerLauncher #1] yarn.ExecutorRunnable (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Setting up ContainerLaunchContext
2016-08-18 18:33:01,691 INFO  [ContainerLauncher #1] yarn.ExecutorRunnable (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Preparing Local resources
2016-08-18 18:33:01,693 INFO  [ContainerLauncher #1] yarn.ExecutorRunnable (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Prepared Local resources Map(__spark__.jar -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "10.2.45.38" port: 8020 file: "/applications/Spark/spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar" } size: 188131212 timestamp: 1470793587683 type: FILE visibility: PRIVATE, __app__.jar -> resource { scheme: "hdfs" host: "10.2.45.38" port: 8020 file: "/applications/Spark/spark-examples-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar" } size: 107624758 timestamp: 1470794155291 type: FILE visibility: PUBLIC)
2016-08-18 18:33:01,704 INFO  [ContainerLauncher #1] yarn.ExecutorRunnable (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - 
===============================================================================
YARN executor launch context:
  env:
    CLASSPATH -> {{PWD}}<CPS>{{PWD}}/__spark__.jar<CPS>$HADOOP_CONF_DIR<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>$HADOOP_COMMON_HOME/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>$HADOOP_HDFS_HOME/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>$HADOOP_YARN_HOME/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*<CPS>$HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_FILE_SIZES -> 107624758,188131212
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_VISIBILITIES -> PUBLIC,PRIVATE
    SPARK_YARN_MODE -> true
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_TIME_STAMPS -> 1470794155291,1470793587683
    SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES -> hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/Spark/spark-examples-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar#__app__.jar,hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/Spark/spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar#__spark__.jar

  command:
    {{JAVA_HOME}}/bin/java -server -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p' -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Djava.io.tmpdir={{PWD}}/tmp '-Dspark.ui.port=0' '-Dspark.driver.port=56446' -Dspark.yarn.app.container.log.dir=<LOG_DIR> org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend --driver-url akka.tcp://sparkDriver@10.2.45.39:56446/user/CoarseGrainedScheduler --executor-id 2 --hostname DPTest1.hdp.ap --cores 1 --app-id application_1471414768581_0125 --user-class-path file:$PWD/__app__.jar 1> <LOG_DIR>/stdout 2> <LOG_DIR>/stderr
===============================================================================

2016-08-18 18:33:01,704 INFO  [ContainerLauncher #1] impl.ContainerManagementProtocolProxy (ContainerManagementProtocolProxy.java:newProxy(260)) - Opening proxy : DPTest1.hdp.ap:45454
2016-08-18 18:33:02,784 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-16] yarn.ApplicationMaster$AMEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Driver terminated or disconnected! Shutting down. DPTest2.hdp.ap:42151
2016-08-18 18:33:03,123 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] cluster.YarnClusterSchedulerBackend (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registered executor: AkkaRpcEndpointRef(Actor[akka.tcp://sparkExecutor@DPTest2.hdp.ap:33082/user/Executor#-1765527969]) with ID 1
2016-08-18 18:33:03,291 INFO  [sparkDriver-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-19] storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint (Logging.scala:logInfo(59)) - Registering block manager DPTest2.hdp.ap:43121 with 530.0 MB RAM, BlockManagerId(1, DPTest2.hdp.ap, 43121)
```

---

the spark-yarn.properties as follows

```
spark.yarn.submit.file.replication=3
spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=384
spark.yarn.driver.memoryOverhead=384
spark.master=yarn
spark.submit.deployMode=cluster
#spark.eventLog.enabled=true
spark.yarn.scheduler.heartbeat.interval-ms=5000
spark.yarn.preserve.staging.files=true
spark.yarn.queue=default
spark.yarn.containerLauncherMaxThreads=25
spark.yarn.max.executor.failures=3
#spark.executor.instances=2
#spark.eventLog.dir=hdfs\://10.2.45.38:8020/tmp/spark-history
spark.history.kerberos.enabled=true
spark.history.provider=org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.history.YarnHistoryProvider
spark.history.ui.port=18080
#spark.history.fs.logDirectory=hdfs\://10.2.45.38:8020/tmp/spark-logDirectory
#spark.executor.memory=1G
#spark.executor.cores=2
spark.history.kerberos.keytab=none
spark.history.kerberos.principal=none
```

the spark-yarn.json as follows

```json
{
  "am-container-spec": {
    "commands": {
      "command": "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_71/bin/java -server -Xmx512m org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster --jar __app__.jar --class org.apache.spark.examples.JavaWordCount --args hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/demo.txt --args hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/output 1>/tmp/sparkAppMaster.stdout 2>/tmp/sparkAppMaster.stderr"
    }, 
    "environment": {
      "entry": [
        {
          "key": "SPARK_YARN_MODE", 
          "value": true
        }, 
        {
          "key": "HDP_VERSION", 
          "value": "2.3.4.7-4"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "CLASSPATH", 
          "value": "__spark__.jar<CPS>__app__.jar<CPS>__app__.properties<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/spark/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/etc/hadoop/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/*<CPS>/usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/*<CPS>/usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/*<CPS>/usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/*<CPS>/usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*<CPS>/usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/*<CPS>/usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*<CPS>/usr/local/lib/hadoop/share/hadoop/tools/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-hdfs-client/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-yarn-client/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop/client/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-mapreduce/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-hdfs/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-yarn/*<CPS>/usr/hdp/2.3.4.7-4/hadoop-yarn/lib/*<CPS>/lib/*<CPS>/etc/hadoop/conf/secure"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES", 
          "value": "hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/Spark/spark-examples-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar#__app__.jar,hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/Spark/spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar#__spark__.jar"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_FILE_SIZES", 
          "value": "107624758,188131212"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_TIME_STAMPS", 
          "value": "1470794155291,1470793587683"
        }, 
        {
          "key": "SPARK_YARN_CACHE_FILES_VISIBILITIES", 
          "value": "PUBLIC,PRIVATE"
        }
      ]
    }, 
    "local-resources": {
      "entry": [
        {
          "key": "__app__.jar", 
          "value": {
            "resource": "hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/Spark/spark-examples-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar", 
            "size": 107624758, 
            "timestamp": 1470794155291, 
            "type": "FILE", 
            "visibility": "APPLICATION"
          }
        }, 
        {
          "key": "__spark__.jar", 
          "value": {
            "resource": "hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/Spark/spark-assembly-1.5.2.2.3.4.7-4-hadoop2.7.1.2.3.4.7-4.jar", 
            "size": 188131212, 
            "timestamp": 1470793587683, 
            "type": "FILE", 
            "visibility": "APPLICATION"
          }
        }, 
        {
          "key": "__app__.properties", 
          "value": {
            "resource": "hdfs://10.2.45.38:8020/applications/Spark/spark-yarn.properties", 
            "size": 817, 
            "timestamp": 1471597245437, 
            "type": "FILE", 
            "visibility": "APPLICATION"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }, 
  "application-id": "application_1471414768581_0171", 
  "application-name": "JavaWordCountTest", 
  "application-type": "SPARK",
  "keep-containers-across-application-attempts": false, 
  "max-app-attempts": 2, 
  "resource": {
    "memory": 1024, 
    "vCores": 1
  }, 
  "unmanaged-AM": false
}
```

An OOM (Out Of Memory) exception is thrown when I submit a spark using Rest api; has anybody else encountered this problem?

Comment: I have made some proofreading changes to your question. On Stack Overflow users are encouraged to edit and re-edit to keep improving the questions as far as possible; if you have any further information to add, or any clarification, feel free to edit the question further.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski: that's " -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError='kill %p'  " where the first snippet area, command's

Comment: I'm specifically asking about the OOME that you could include in your post so I could have a context.